# Excel VBA - Get Data from SQL based of Cell range values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been tasked to get data from a SQL DB based off the values in Column A Row 3 onwards.

Example of Excel Sheet:

```
ITEM   | QTY TO PICK | QTY ON ORDER | Column 2 | Column 3 etc

PART 1 |      5      | <Data will be populated here>

PART 2 |      12     | <Data will be populated here>
```

This code runs through a Command Button.

The data pulled from SQL will be populated starting in C3 onwards.

However, my below code only returns one row at a time.

I know where I need to make changes, I just don't know what. After at least 2 hours googling, I'm thoroughly stumped.

```
ItemNumber = Range("A3").Value
```

I've tried amending to `("A3:A100").Value` but I just get errors.

Full code below;

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "server=<server name>;INITIAL CATALOG=<DB Name>;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cn.Open strConn

'
'

ActiveSheet.Range("C3:G10000").Clear ' clear out existing data
Dim ItemNumber As String

ItemNumber = Range("A3").Value

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

SQLStr = "Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO = " & ItemNumber & ""

rs.Open SQLStr, cn

' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
Sheet4.Range("C3").CopyFromRecordset rs

' Tidy up

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Not tested : I think you'll need to do it like this `Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO in (select [a3:a100] from [Sheet1$])`  or use a loop or a filter or dump the rst temporarily and use a `vlookup`

Comment: I see where you're going, tried the first option. Changed `[Sheet1$]` to `[Sheet4$]` but I get `Invalid Object name 'Sheet4'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try building the SQL like so

```
"Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO in (" & _
join(application.transpose(range("a1:a5").Value),",") & ")"
```

or, for strings.

```
  "Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO in ('" & _
join(application.transpose(range("a1:a5").Value),"','") & "')"
```

Comment: I used the second option as I'm using strings, which worked. Is there a way to get the returned data to be in line with the ITEM value its for? They've come through in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is:

1.)

Create a table on SQL Server which contains parameters for your sql statement (itemnumber = 1)

2.)
Write a cycle which loops tru the ranges and adds values one by one to the table like:

i = 1
while cells(i,3).value <> ""
... Insert into temptable values (parameter1,parameter2, etc)

i = i+1
wend

3.)

Modify your sql statement for the recordset joining the table with the parameters and the data you would like to pull and paste that data.

Comment: I'm unable to create new tables. Instead I have a created a view that contains all the data I need to display.